# How to call a vue method from bootstrap-select listener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, scope, bootstrap-select

I have a vue with vuex reactive auto-saving app, and I'm using [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/) as one of the fields to try to autosave.

I declare the bootstrap-select listener in the vue component's mounted() lifecycle hook like so:

```
mounted() {  //vue mounted hook
    const selectpicker = $(this.$el).find('.selectpicker')

    selectpicker.selectpicker('val', this.selected);  //this shows previously saved 'selected' items

    function callback() {
      this.callVueComponentMethod()  //throws 'this.* is not a function'
    }

    selectpicker.selectpicker().on('changed.bs.select', callback()); 
}
```

I declare it in the mounted hook as this is how I got it to work best... but now I want to try to `$emit` a function to the parent vue component when a selection changes on the bootstrap-select so I need to somehow access the `this` object in the bootstrap-select listener to call the $emit up the chain to eventually save the selection change.

I could be missing something but I feel like the problem is getting the `this` object into the selectpicker listener scope?

Appreciate any and all advice!! thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried listening to the `@change` event directly on the `<select></select>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function which solve `this` problem.

```
let callback = () => {
  this.callVueComponentMethod();
}
```

To learn more about `this` you can [read](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e) this.

Comment: Thanks @sugars I ended up doing a v-model on the select tag and added a computed set function that I was able to use to $emit the newly selected values to the parent vue, I must remember to trust in vue! thanks